# What replacement wings are available for old F-16s?

Tags: wing, aircraft-maintenance, f-16

Eventually, material fatigue will force any aircraft to either be grounded or have its wings rebuilt, or replaced. And please, correct me if I'm wrong.

For the F-16, if one were to replace its wings, what alternatives are there?

Are wings for the F-16 still made, as they were in the 1970s, or does multiple modern alternatives also exist? Can you buy e.g. carbon fiber wings for the F-16? What about other composite materials?

If not, why not? Is the performance different negligible and not worth the cost compared to the original wing?

As a bonus question: If there are indeed more high performance wings, such as carbon fiber wings available for the F-16, how does the performance of the aircraft overall, and especially in a dogfight get affected? I imagine all such studies are classified, if they exist at all, but if they are public, I'd love to see such a study.

Comment: *"And please, correct me if I'm wrong."* I believe you are very much off-base here. If anything was fatigued it would be the main spar (in the case of the F-16, there are multiple), not the wing.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Thanks for that, I didn't know.